# Why does my UITableViewController only have interesting subviews after viewDidAppear?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

### Initial Question:

I have a UITableViewController "tvc" created from the storyboard as a static cell table. Each cell contains a UILabel and an UITextField. I desire to iterate through all the UITextFields and mess with their properties. My solution is to iterate through the tvc.tableView.subviews, and their subviews and so on. Using the code below.

```
@implementation UIView (GWExtensions)

-(void) enumerateAllSubviewsWithBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)) block {
     [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
          block(obj,idx,stop);
          if (*stop) {
                return;
          }
          [(UIView*)obj enumerateAllSubviewsWithBlock:block];
     }];
}
```

and in the UITableViewController viewDidLoad method:

```
[self.tableView enumerateAllSubviewsWithBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   NSLog(@"\n\n=== SubView: %@", obj);
}];
```

and what I get in the log is

```
=== SubView: <UIImageView: 0xa1ea760; frame = (0 476; 320 3); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa1ea840>> - (null)
=== SubView: <UIImageView: 0xa1ea980; frame = (316 390; 3 65); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa1eaa60>> - (null)
```

So from this I conclude my UITableViewController contains 2 UIImageViews. Which is clearly madness.

### More details after some feedback:

This is interesting. Running po [self.view recursiveDescription] in the viewDidLoad after [super viewDidLoad] yielded the following:

```
<UITableView: 0xbadc400; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa5dd570>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5dcf20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    | <UIImageView: 0xa5dd120; frame = (0 476; 320 3); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5dd200>> - (null)
    | <UIImageView: 0xa5dd340; frame = (316 390; 3 65); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5dd420>> - (null)
```

Running po [self.view recursiveDescription] in viewWillAppear ALSO yielded:

```
<UITableView: 0xbadc400; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa5dd570>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5dcf20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    | <UIImageView: 0xa5dd120; frame = (0 476; 320 3); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5dd200>> - (null)
    | <UIImageView: 0xa5dd340; frame = (316 390; 3 65); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5dd420>> - (null)
```

But, running po [self.view recursiveDescription] in viewDidAppear give interesting results:

```
<UITableView: 0xa8d3a00; frame = (0 64; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa287c20>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa27de10>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8bed650; frame = (0 275; 320 46); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bed7c0>>
    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8bee2a0; frame = (0 0; 320 46); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8bee530>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bee470>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8bed810; frame = (0 0; 287 44.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8beee80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bed880>>
    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8bed8d0; frame = (10 13; 76 20); text = 'Type'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bed970>>
    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8bedbf0; frame = (94 13; 216 20); text = 'Cadet'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bedc90>>
    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x8bee9b0; frame = (297 16; 8 12.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8beea90>>
    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8beeb80; frame = (0 0; 8 12.5); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8beec10>> - (null)
    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8beab60; frame = (0 231; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8beacd0>>
    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8becdd0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8bed040>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8becfa0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8bead20; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8bed610>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bead90>>
    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8beade0; frame = (10 11.5; 76 21); text = 'Years'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8beae80>>
    |    |    |    | <UITextField: 0x8beb130; frame = (94 7; 216 30); text = '0'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8bebd90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8beb270>>
    |    |    |    |    | <_UIBaselineLayoutStrut: 0x8bec8f0; frame = (0 4.5; 0 21); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bec990>>
    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x8beb4b0; frame = (0 0; 216 30); text = '0'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8beb550>>
    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8be82f0; frame = (0 187; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be8460>>
    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8bea2d0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8bea540>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bea4a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8be84b0; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8beab20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be8520>>
    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8be8570; frame = (10 11.5; 76 21); text = 'Grade'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be8610>>
    |    |    |    | <UITextField: 0x8be8860; frame = (94 7; 216 30); text = '0'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be93b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be89a0>>
    |    |    |    |    | <_UIBaselineLayoutStrut: 0x8be9e00; frame = (0 4.5; 0 21); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be9ea0>>
    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x8be8b80; frame = (0 0; 216 30); text = '0'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be8c20>>
    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8be5c40; frame = (0 143; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be5db0>>
    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8be7b50; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be7da0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be7d20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8be5e00; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be82d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be5e70>>
    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8be5ec0; frame = (10 11.5; 76 21); text = 'Birthday'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be5f60>>
    |    |    |    | <UITextField: 0x8be61b0; frame = (94 12; 216 20); text = 'Aug 6, 2140'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be6d00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be62f0>>
    |    |    |    |    | <_UIBaselineLayoutStrut: 0x8be7720; frame = (0 -0.5; 0 21); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be77c0>>
    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x8be64d0; frame = (0 0; 216 20); text = 'Aug 6, 2140'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be6570>>
    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8be3380; frame = (0 99; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be34f0>>
    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8be5480; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be56f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be5650>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8be3520; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be5c20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be3590>>
    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8be35c0; frame = (10 11.5; 76 21); text = 'Parent'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be3660>>
    |    |    |    | <UITextField: 0x8be3870; frame = (94 7; 216 30); text = 'Sabrina'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be4440>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be39b0>>
    |    |    |    |    | <_UIBaselineLayoutStrut: 0x8be4f80; frame = (0 4.5; 0 21); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be5020>>
    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x8be3b90; frame = (0 0; 216 30); text = 'Sabrina'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be3c30>>
    | <UITableViewCell: 0x8bde3f0; frame = (0 55; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bc3e30>>
    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8be2a00; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be2c70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be2bd0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x8bde300; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be3360>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bcd980>>
    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8bde560; frame = (10 11.5; 76 21); text = 'Name'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bde370>>
    |    |    |    | <UITextField: 0x8bde760; frame = (94 7; 216 30); text = 'JoAnne Powell'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8be19c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bde8a0>>
    |    |    |    |    | <_UIBaselineLayoutStrut: 0x8bde8d0; frame = (0 4.5; 0 21); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be12e0>>
    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x8bdf940; frame = (0 0; 216 30); text = 'JoAnne Powell'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bdfa40>>
    | <UIImageView: 0xa269c80; frame = (0 363; 320 3); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa272790>> - (null)
    | <UITableViewHeaderFooterView: 0xf17bb60; frame = (0 0; 320 55); text = 'SCOUT'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xf17bc20>>
    |    | <_UITableViewHeaderFooterViewBackground: 0xf17bd40; frame = (0 0; 320 55); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xf17bdb0>>
    |    | <_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView: 0xf17bc50; frame = (0 0; 320 55); layer = <CALayer: 0xf17bcb0>>
    |    |    | <_UITableViewHeaderFooterViewLabel: 0xf17be40; frame = (15 31.5; 49 17); text = 'SCOUT'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xf17bef0>>
    | <UITableViewHeaderFooterView: 0xf17c440; frame = (0 331; 320 37.5); text = 'CONTACT'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xf17c500>>
    |    | <_UITableViewHeaderFooterViewBackground: 0xf17c630; frame = (0 0; 320 37.5); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xf17c6a0>>
    |    | <_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView: 0xf17c530; frame = (0 0; 320 37.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xf17c590>>
    |    |    | <_UITableViewHeaderFooterViewLabel: 0xf17c730; frame = (15 14; 66 17); text = 'CONTACT'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xf17c7e0>>
    | <UIImageView: 0xa284610; frame = (316 390; 3 65); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa2846a0>> - (null)
```

So I don't seem to be able to manipulate the UITextFields until after the View Appears. This doesn't make sense. Is this correct? How can I fiddle with the bits before they appear?

Comment: What's the cause of your surprise? is it because you never instantiated those UIImageViews through storyboard nor programmatically? It is very possible that Apple creates such ImageViews for internal implementation of some features specific to a UITableViewCell (think of when you click on a cell and it gets highlighted.. I remember when I was debugging that part of my code I ran into some surprises as well)

Comment: My surprise is those 2 UIImageViews are ALL of the subviews.

Comment: In viewDidLoad, call reloadData on the table then call recursiveDescriotion.

Comment: interesting. The exact same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.tableView recursiveDescription]);
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html

To avoid compiler errors:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.view performSelector:@selector(recursiveDescription)]);
```

Comment: This isn't exactly the answer, but it did help my figure out what my question is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation instead:

```
- (void)enumerateAllSubviewsWithBlock:(void (^)(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stopOut))block {
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        BOOL stop = NO;
        block(subview, index++, &stop);
        if (stop) {
            return;
        }

        [subview enumerateAllSubviewsWithBlock:block];
    };
}

[self.tableView enumerateAllSubviewsWithBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"\n\n=== SubView: %@", view);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you. I've learned the issue isn't with the enumeration. The TVC view hierarchy isn't set until  viewDidAppear.